# PyDev Install Issue. (PyDev/Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I am trying to install PyDev on my Eclipse 06-2020 version. When I go to the marketplace and select PyDev. I keep seeing the error:

> The following solutions are not available: PyDev - Python IDE for Eclipse 7.6.0 (id=org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group, org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature.feature.group, site=http://www.pydev.org/updates/)

Is it the newer version that is causing the problem? Can I try to install and older version if that works? Please help!

Comment: Does the following update site work? [`https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/7.6.0/`](https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/7.6.0/)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't too.  Already tried that before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but having trashed my eclipse setup recently and reinstalled 2020-06 I found I couldn't install latest version of PyDev 8.3.0 because I don't have Java 11. I could though install PyDev 8.2.0 via update site https://www.pydev.org/update_sites/8.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Eclipse version 4.29.0. What solved the problem for me was following the installation instructions from the [PyDev website](https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html). Here I quote the steps from the webpage below:

> **Installing with the update site**
>
> Note: Instructions are targeted at Eclipse 4.6 onwards
>
> To install PyDev and PyDev Extensions using the Eclipse Update
> Manager, you need to use the Help > Install New Software... menu. In the next screen, add the update site(s) you want to work with from the
> list below:
>
> Latest version: http://www.pydev.org/updates
>
> Nightly builds:
> http://www.pydev.org/nightly
>
> Browse other versions (open in browser to
> select URL for Eclipse): http://www.pydev.org/update_sites and press  so that Eclipse
> will query the update site you just entered for contents.
>
> Before proceeding, it's recommended that you UNCHECK the 'Contact all
> update sites during install to find required software' (it will still
> work if you don't do that, but it'll query all the update sites
> available, which is much slower than querying only the PyDev update
> site, which should be all that's needed to install PyDev).
>
> Now, select PyDev for Eclipse to install PyDev (and optionally the
> PyDev Mylyn integration or the developer resources, which provide the
> PyDev source code) and click Next.
>
> Now, read the license agreement and if you accept, select the accept
> radio button and click Finish.
>
> At that point, Eclipse should automatically download the plugin
> contents and present you to a dialog asking if you want to restart (to
> which you should say yes).